# Change the height of UITableViewCells when using static cells in Storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, storyboard

Is it possible to resize `UITableViewCells` or `UITableView` sections when using static cells in `Storyboards`?

I would like some cells to be shorter than others in the same way that the Contacts app has shorter cells in order to make space for the picture. I'm trying to do this using static cells in storyboards instead of programatically.

Answer (score 2):

In your table view controller, implement the following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // The first cell
            return 25.0;
        else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            return 44.0;
        }
    }
    // Default
    return 30.0;
}
```

Comment: Did this help with your problem?